# @SafeVarargs in vararg method with generic return type

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, variadic-functions, type-safety

My `query` method below facilitates queries to my persistence layer using `org.hibernate.Session`. Here is the method code:

```
public class Persister{

    public static <E> List<E> query(Class<E> c, E... exampleEntities){
        try(Session session = openSession()){
            final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(c);
            for(E e : exampleEntities){
                final Example example = Example.create(e);
                criteria.add(example);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final List<E> list = criteria.list();
            /*
             * Empty loop technique ensures all elements in list are of type E
             * otherwise a ClassCastException is thrown. Inspired by
             * "Java Generics" section 8.2
             */
            for(E e : list);
            return list;
        }
    }

    //other methods ommitted
}
```

It raises the following warning:

> Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter exampleEntities

**Is it safe to use the `@SafeVarargs` annotation in this case?**

As I understand it, as long as I'm not initializing a local `Object[]` with `exampleEntities`, then I'm okay. But that doesn't seem right.

This method *is* similar to the method [`java.util.Collections.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)) mentioned in [the Java Specification §9.6.3.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.7), which is annotated with `@SafeVarargs`.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231037/java-safevarargs-annotation-does-a-standard-or-best-practice-exist/14252221#14252221) discusses the warning, saying that in general the following code is safe:

```
@SafeVarargs
void foo(T... args) {
    for (T x : args) {
        // do stuff with x
    }
}
```

But my `query` method is of the form:

```
<T> List<T> query(T... args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    for (T x : args) {
        foo.add(x);
    }
    return (List<T>) foo.list();
}
```

So, is there a case where the `@SafeVarargs` annotation would not be safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `@SafeVarargs`. Whether you can use `@SafeVarargs` depends on how you use the varargs parameter `exampleEntities`. If you rely on its actual runtime type being an `E[]`, then you cannot use `@SafeVarargs`, but if you only rely on its elements' types being `E`, then you can use `@SafeVarargs`.

Here, you only iterate over `exampleEntities` and get `E` out of it. That is consistent with `@SafeVarargs`.