# Why usage of generic varargs gives warning but de-sugared version does not?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

Consider these two methods:

```
// All good...
static <T> T extractFirst(T[] arr) {
    if (arr.length > 0) return arr[0];
    return null;
}

// Warning: "possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type"
static <T> T extractFirstVarargs(T... arr) {
    if (arr.length > 0) return arr[0];
    return null;
}
```

The compiler gives a warning for the second method, but not for the first method which is just the de-sugared version of it. Why is that?

As far as I understand, I can produce unsafe code whenever I work with array types (since they are covariant due to historical reasons) or raw container types. How varargs factor into this is not clear to me.

**EDIT**: I know what heap pollution and type erasure is. But I fail to see why the warning is not also present in `extractFirst` since I can cause heap pollution there as well.

**EDIT 2**: The warning doesn't even relate to generic params (`T`), it also appears when using something like `List<String>...` as a formal param.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible heap pollution via varargs parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462079/possible-heap-pollution-via-varargs-parameter)

Comment: Also worth reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.7, [Java: "Heap pollution"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/155994), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. However, I still fail to see why all of that does not apply to `T[]`. Why is the "variable arity" so important if all examples that show unsafe code would be equally unsafe if `T[]` were used as the formal argument type?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252221 (especially last example)

Comment: @Pshemo This is exactly what I was missing! Effectively, a potential generic caller must new-up the implicit array `T[]` without actually knowing T, therefore falling-back to `Object[]`, and that is the actual problem here. ;)

Comment: OK, I just realized that the same warning also appears if the signature looks like this instead: `extractFirstVarargs(List<String>... arr)`, but doesn't appear if de-sugared like this: `extractFirst(List<String>[] arr)` The argument about generic params doesn't apply here though, so what's the explanation in this case?