# Java: varargs in interface

Tags: java, variadic-functions

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public ArrayList<Double> f(ArrayList<Double>... args);
}
```

I get the warning: `Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter paramOfChildren`. I can suppress this warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

However, in every class that implements this interface, I get this warning again. I wonder if there's a way to suppress this warning once for all the classes implementing the interface. If not, is there a good reason that we shouldn't do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462079/potential-heap-pollution-via-varargs-parameter)

Comment: Well I've read that discussion before asking. It doesn't provide a solution to my question. In particular, "@SafeVarargs" cannot be used since it is in an interface.

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37829160/113632) - suggestion there is to create a static helper method to convert from varargs to `List`.

Answer (score -2):

you can pin down the generic:

```
class DoubleList extends ArrayList<Double> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

interface MyInterface {
    public DoubleList f(DoubleList... args);
}
```

Comment: This technically works, but it defeats the purpose of using generics.