# Interface with multiple generic parameters

Tags: java, android

I have the following interface:

```
public interface DataLoadedListener<T> {
    void onDataLoaded(T... data);
}
```

But on "onDataLoaded" i get the following warning: 
"Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type"

Cah someone explain me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Information about "possible heap pollution" are available [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462079/potential-heap-pollution-via-varargs-parameter) or [on this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/155994/java-heap-pollution). But there are black magic like `@SuppressWarning` or `@SafeVarargs` if you just don't want to see these warning...

Comment: See also [Oracle's detailed explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html).