# Are there type-safe and more concise alternatives of the generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I find generics good for fostering generalization and promoting type safety through removal of casting. Sometimes however I feel like the produced code is much larger for the added value. Are there special cases where the superfluous generics code is avoided and the type-safety not regressed?

For example I have a small invariant utility which among other things check whether a composite object (e.g. Collection of Strings or String of chars) is empty. When the invariant is not kept, the utility raises a predefined exception. It looks tempting to use generic for the type of the class object to avoid casting.

```
public interface Invariant<T> {
    void enforce(@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T... arg) throws RuntimeException;
}

public class StringNotEmpty implements Invariant<String> {
    @Override
    public void enforce(String... arg) throws RuntimeException {
        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
            if (arg[i].trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

public class CollectionNotEmpty<T> implements Invariant<T extends Collection> {
    @Override
    public void enforce(@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T... arg) throws RuntimeException {
        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
            if (arg[i].isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how the invariant utility is used:

```
public void aMethod(String aString, String bString, List<Integer> aList) {
    Invariant<String> inv1 = new StringNotEmpty();
    Invariant<? extends List<Integer> inv2 = new CollectionNotEmpty<List<Integer>>();

    // Throw runtime exception when invariant1 is not kept
    inv1.enforce(aString, bString);

    // Do some business...

    // Throw runtime exception when invariant2 is not kept
    inv2.enforce(aList);
}
```

The end-result is mediocre: Invariants are mouthful to use, and the type safety is compromised: See the supress-warnings annotation which just [masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462079/potential-heap-pollution-via-varargs-parameter) the risky attempt to use template for varargs.

Could the "invariant" API be made more concise, yet keep its type-safety?

Comment: I'm liking this question a lot, but it doesn't exactly fit into the Q&A style here at Stack Overflow.  If you reworded this into a question and supplied what you have as your current question as an answer, it'd probably work a lot better.  To that effect, I've started a Meta discussion about this question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293771/1079354).

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. Although this site has been invaluable as reference for my work, I am still new as publisher. Rephrased the question in attempt to match the site's Q&A style. Looking forward your feedback.

Comment: I've cast a reopen vote.  It should make its easy through the review queue and hopefully be reopened.