# How to pass a list of Class as parameter?

Tags: java, exception

I was trying to have a `handleException` method, which can take an exception object and a list of acceptable exception classes to check if the exception is acceptable and can be retried.

```
void handleException(Exception e, String... acceptableExceptionNames)
      throws MyException {

    boolean isRetryable = false;

    for(String acceptableExceptionName: acceptableExceptionNames) {
      try {
        if (Class.forName(acceptableExceptionName).isInstance(e)) {
          isRetryable = true;
          break;
        }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        continue;
      }
    }

    if (isRetryable) {
      // log retryable
    } else {
      // log error
    }

    throw new MyException(isRetryable, "Failed");
  }
```

The parameter I pass in is a `String... classNames` instead of `Class<? extends Exception> classes`, because if I do something like this:

```
void handleException(
    Exception e,
    Class<? extends Exception>... acceptableExceptions)
      throws MyException {
    for (Class acceptableException : acceptableExceptions) {
        if (e instanceOf acceptableException) {}
    }
}
```

The IDE will complain about `unknown class acceptableException`

Anyone knows if there's a way to pass `Class<?>`? Or a better way to avoid using `String classNames` and `Class.forName()`?

Comment: You can't use a generic type in Exceptions!

Comment: When you use varargs, the type of `acceptableExceptions` is `Class[]`.

Comment: Why did you try `e instanceOf acceptableExceptions` with an array of Classes? You demonstrated you know how to iterate over an array and call the `Class.isInstance` method in the other snippet.

Comment: instead of String array, pass Class[] ?

Comment: I'm just too lazy to write the for loop line... So just find the problem. `e instanceOf classVariable` is not working, but `calssVariable.isInstance(e)` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`acceptableExceptions` isn't a `Class`, it's a `Class[]`. You can keep your original design, though, and just use the `Class` objects directly instead of creating them from strings:

```
void handleException
        (Exception e, Class<? extends Exception>... acceptableExceptionNames)
        throws MyException {

    boolean isRetryable = false;

    for(Class<?> acceptableExceptionName: acceptableExceptionNames) {
        if (acceptableExceptionName.isInstance(e)) {
            isRetryable = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isRetryable) {
        // log retryable
    } else {
        // log error
    }

    throw new MyException(isRetryable, "Failed");
}
```

EDIT:
As a side note, this code can be made considerably shorter using Java 8's streams:

```
void handleException
        (Exception e, Class<? extends Exception>... acceptableExceptionNames)
        throws MyException {

    boolean isRetryable = 
        Arrays.stream(acceptableExceptionNames).anyMatch(x -> x.isInstance(e));

    if (isRetryable) {
        // log retryable
    } else {
        // log error
    }

    throw new MyException(isRetryable, "Failed");
}
```

Comment: Why replace `Class<? extends Exception>` with `Class<?>`? You are no longer restricting the class types.

Comment: @Andreas because `Class<? extends Exception>` will result in a heap-polution warning via `acceptableExceptionNames`, though I do not fully understand why this warning occurs.

Comment: What "heap-polution warning"? My Eclipse is giving no such warning.

Comment: @Andreas `javac -d ..\bin Main.java -Xlint:unchecked` -> `Main.java:8: warning: [unchecked] Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type Class<? extends Exception>`

Comment: @Andreas Good point - no good reason, just wasn't paying attention when I copy-pasted and edited OP's code. Edited and fixed.

Comment: The heap pollution warning could be solved by making the method `final` and adding a `@SafeVarags` annotation to it. Didn't want to distract attention from the core of the answer, but this is a change that can easily be applied to the real code.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to check if `e` is an instance of a `Class[]`, which is what `acceptableExceptions` is, but if it is an instance of *one of* the classes referenced by the `acceptableExceptions` array.

To do that, you need to iterate them, and you need to use the reflection method [`Class.isInstance(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-). As the javadoc says:

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator.

To prevent compiler warnings, you also need to add `@SafeVarargs` to you method if it is `static` or `final`. Otherwise, you need to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to both the method and it's caller(s).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void handleException(Exception e, Class<? extends Exception>... acceptableExceptions) throws MyException {
    boolean acceptable = false;
    for (Class<? extends Exception> acceptableException : acceptableExceptions)
        if (acceptableException.isInstance(e)) {
            acceptable = true;
            break;
        }
    if (acceptable) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `@SafeVarargs` doesn't apply to non-final instance methods with varargs. If that is needed, you'll end up with [`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462079/potential-heap-pollution-via-varargs-parameter).

Comment: @dhke You're right. I had made the method `static` in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's easier to do if by performing the simple String Comparisons like this:

```
private void handleException(Exception ex, String... acceptableException) {
    for (int x = 0; x < acceptableException.length; x++) {
        String[] exceptionClass = ex.getClass().toString().split(".");
        if (!acceptableException[x]
                .equals(exceptionClass[exceptionClass.length - 1])) {
            /* Exception Not Acceptable */
        }
    }

    /* Exception Acceptable */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use following checking

```
for (Class<? extends Exception> exceptionClass : acceptableExceptions) {
    if (exceptionClass.isInstance(e)) {
        // it is your exception
    }
}
```