# JOOQ Field class bounded to Record only (without type)

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to create a generic type-safe method to fetch some fields from row by primary key like this:

```
/**
 * Abstract Generic DAO Layer for BaseEntity
 *
 * RB - Record Bean
 * EB - Entity Bean
 * PK - Primary key type
*/
public interface AbstractDao<RB extends TableRecord, EB extends BaseEntity, PK> {

    /**
     * Fetches specified fields by given primary key
     */
    Optional<EB> findById(PK id, TableField<RB, ?>... fields);

}
```

Whereas it works fine, the problem is that I can't provide a field type as a 2nd generic argument here:

```
TableField<RB, ?>... fields
```

Since it's known to field itself only and it leads to possible [heap pollution issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462079/potential-heap-pollution-via-varargs-parameter?rq=1).

I'd gladly change my signature to:

```
Optional<EB> findById(PK id, Field<RB>... fields);
```

But `Field` only accepts its type as generic parameter, not the record type.

Is there any child/parent of Field class which is bounded to its Record type within JOOQ code base?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that your interface signature is wrong. You cannot use the  `TableRecord` raw type. You should declare `RB extends TableRecord<RB>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any child/parent of Field class which is bounded to its Record type within JOOQ code base?

`TableField<R extends Record, T>` is the type you're looking for. Any other type that would offer a reference to `<R>` would have the exact same issue as the one you ran into, and it would not offer any semantic advantage over `TableField`

Anyway, just suppress the warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Optional<EB> findById(PK id, TableField<RB, ?>... fields);
```

After all, these heap pollution warnings when using varargs are really annoying and more of a flaw of the language, than of your API.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, it's helpful.